# Возвращаемый тип функции(основывается на данных класса) должен быть конвертируем в несколько других типов. Как правильно выстроить архитектуру?

Tags: java, архитектура, интерфейс

Возьмем за основу, что преобразовать из возвращаемого типа ф-ции в другие можно только зная тип класса(в которой находится эта ф-ция), ибо возвращаемый тип ф-ции напрямую зависит от вычислений, производимых в процессе парса.
В голову сразу же приходит следующее решение: создать класс-парсер, в котором много ф-ций parse, которые преобразовывают возвращаемый тип ф-ции в другие типы. Но тогда обозначить, что это парсер, можно только через интерфейс без методов. И тогда вся абстракция рушится - мы начинаем зависеть от конкретной реализации. Как поступить? Может, я изначально неправильно систему построил, и эта проблема неискоренима?

Если нужно, вот текст программы:

```
public interface Crashable<OutputType, ToBreakDeterminator> {
    boolean hasCrushed();
    default boolean canBreakDown(CrasherUI<OutputType, ToBreakDeterminator> crasher) { // проверять должен CrasherUI.canCrash()!
        return crasher.canCrash(this);
    }
    OutputType breakDown(CrasherUI<OutputType, ToBreakDeterminator> crasherUI) throws IllegalStateException;
    ToBreakDeterminator getToBreakDeterminator();   
}

public class Thing implements Crashable<String, Integer>{
    private Integer rigidity;
    private String name;

    private CrasherUI crushedBy;

    public final static Integer DEFAULT_RIGIDITY = 50;
    public final static String DEFAULT_NAME = "unnamed";

    {
        crushedBy = null;
    }

    //...

    @Override
    public String breakDown(CrasherUI<String, Integer> crasher) throws IllegalStateException {
        if(hasCrushed()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("It is already crushed by " + crushedBy);
        }
        crushedBy = crasher;
        return "u broke " + name + " with " + rigidity + " by " + crasher + ", dude"; 
        // это возврат ф-ции. По-идее должен возвращать уже OutputType(см абстрактный класс)
    }

    //...
}
```

А вот сам абстрактный класс:

```
public abstract class AbstractApartaments<OutputType, InputType, ToBreakDeterminator> implements ApartamentUI{
    private Stack<? extends Crashable<InputType, ToBreakDeterminator>> things;

    private CrasherUI<InputType, ToBreakDeterminator> crasher;

    private Function<InputType, OutputType> inputToOutput; // один тип(Crashable) только обрабатывать можем. 
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<OutputType> toUserOutputs;
    private ToUserOutputUI<OutputType> out;

    {
        things = new Stack();
        toUserOutputs = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();
    }

    public AbstractApartaments(Collection<? extends Crashable<InputType, ToBreakDeterminator>> toCrush, CrasherUI<InputType, ToBreakDeterminator> crasher, Function<InputType, OutputType> inputToOutput, ToUserOutputUI<OutputType> out){
        things.addAll(toCrush); // Ошибка!
        this.crasher = crasher;
        this.inputToOutput = inputToOutput;
        this.out = out;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean hasThingsToCrash() {
        return things.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean crashNext() {
        if(!things.isEmpty()) {
            Crashable<InputType, ToBreakDeterminator> toCrash = things.pop();
            if(toCrash.canBreakDown(crasher)) {
                toUserOutputs.add(inputToOutput.apply(toCrash.breakDown(crasher)));
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void pullToUserOutputs() {
        while(!toUserOutputs.isEmpty()) {
            out.toOutput(toUserOutputs.poll());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Дженерики не подходят?

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Хмм, жестко ограничить список типов, в которые возможен парс? А чтобы не иметь жесткое ограничение достаточно сделать скелет из интерфейсов... Но тогда возникает проблема - кое-где в абстрактном классе я использую эту ф-цию преобразования. И мне нужен конкретный тип на выходе(результат одной из ф-ций parse), который указан в дженерике абстрактного класса. Вот тогда-то и можно опереться на наш скелет, в котором нижние элементы представляют собой Parser<T, V>{V parse(T t);}. То есть можно просто подставлять нужный парсер на место интерфейса.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica А можно как-то регулировать кол-во одинаковых наследуемых интерфейсов? Как-то не чисто выглядит Paser2<From, A, B>, Parser3<From, A, B, C>, Parser4<From, A, B, C, D> и тд.

Comment: @Miron добавьте, пожалуйста пример  кода в вопрос, по тексту очень тяжело воспринимается.

Comment: @Miron Чтоб ответить по поводу изначально правильно/неправильно построенной архитектуры - надо знать какие именно проблемы вы пытаетесь решить. Ну и видеть что у вас получилось. Если проект в открытом доступе, можете кинуть ссылку для ознакомления.

Comment: Я тоже не вкурил, даже с учетом того что сейчас 9-45

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Добавил код.

Comment: Вообще, я старался сделать наиболее гибкую архитектуру. Читал, вот, накануне "Чистую архитектуру", и решил следовать ее советам... Прямо чувствую гибкость, и пытаюсь ее сохранить.

Comment: @Miron Хорошая книга, советую так же "Совершенный код" и "Приемы объектно-ориентированного программирования Паттерны проектирования"  если не читали.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica нет, опереться на скелет нельзя - записать "interface Parser3<From, A, B, C>  extends Parser<From, A>, Parser<From, B>, Parser<From, C>{}" нельзя

Comment: @Miron имхо, наиболее гибкая архитектура - жуткое усложнение, гибкость должна быть необходимая и достаточная.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Ну, под гибкостью я сейчас имею ввиду независимость от конкретных типов. Ее я сейчас и добиваюсь

Comment: @Miron честно говоря, очень переусложнено, и не понятно какую проблему вы решаете. Вы хотите чтоб в методе crashNext() в toUserOutputs добавлялся любой тип реализующий Crashable?

Comment: Опишите что должен делать этот код, точнее вся программа

Comment: @Z.John да. То есть я не завишу от конкретных реализаций - в этом и сила. "Проблема" - Есть уничтожатор. Им можно уничтожать объекты в квартире. Уничтожатор и объект сравнивают свои спец-объекты для получения ответа на вопрос - может ли уничтожатор уничтожить объект. Уничтожаем, если можем. Выводим результат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пометьте что ваша очередь может принимать любой тип наследованный от Crashable

```
public abstract class AbstractApartaments<InputType, ToBreakDeterminator> implements ApartamentUI{
private Stack<Crashable> things;
private CrasherUI crasher;
private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Crashable> toUserOutputs;
private ToUserOutputUI<OutputType> out;

{
    things = new Stack<>();
    toUserOutputs = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
}

public AbstractApartaments( Collection<? extends Crashable<InputType, ToBreakDeterminator>> toCrush,
                            CrasherUI<InputType, ToBreakDeterminator> crasher,
                            ToUserOutputUI<OutputType> out){

    this.things.addAll(toCrush);
    this.crasher = crasher;
    this.out = out;
}


@Override
public boolean hasThingsToCrash() {
    return things.isEmpty();
}

@Override
public boolean crashNext() {
    if(!things.isEmpty()) {
        Crashable toCrash = things.pop();
        if(toCrash.canBreakDown(crasher)) {
            toUserOutputs.add(toCrash.breakDown(crasher));
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
}

@Override
public void pullToUserOutputs() {
    while(!toUserOutputs.isEmpty()) {
        out.toOutput(toUserOutputs.poll());
    }
}

}
```

Comment: @Miron если я вас правильно понял, примерно так, но не уверен что я вас правильно понял. Дженерики и правда мощная вещь, но они далеко не всегда нужны для создании гибкой архитектуры. В вашем примере абсолютно точно не правильная архитектура. Если есть желание,  выложите проект на github или bitbucket - могу посмотреть, подсказать по архитектуре.

Comment: Не дает передать ссылку  объекта "Collection<? extends Crashable<InputType, ToBreakDeterminator>>" в "Stack<? extends Crashable<InputType, ToBreakDeterminator>>". Выдает следующую ошибку: "The method addAll(Collection<? extends capture#2-of ? extends Crashable<InputType,ToBreakDeterminator>>) in the type Vector<capture#2-of ? extends Crashable<InputType,ToBreakDeterminator>> is not applicable for the arguments (Collection<capture#3-of ? extends Crashable<InputType,ToBreakDeterminator>>)"

Comment: @Miron да, надо передать ему дженерики которые вы используете в интерфейсе. И вы не инициализируете `crasher`.

Comment: И там, и там же указано "? extends Crashable<InputType, ToBreakDeterminator>". Чем эти записи не идентичны? crasher указывается в конструкторе, я это опустил.

Comment: надо смотреть, так ничего не подскажу

Comment: Добавил полный код абстрактного класса

Comment: я поправил ответ

Comment: Хорошее исправление, теперь я могу использовать разные реализации Crashable<InputType, ToBreakDeterminator>. Но есть проблема - каждая конкретная реализация должна иметь свой класс-парсер(из InputType в OutputType). Его-то я и планирую возвращать. А "Apartaments" уже должен выбирать нужный метод для того, чтобы преобразовать к нужному типу. Думаю, нужно сделать метод, который будет принимать переменную типа Class(даже не знаю, как ее получить, буду искать), к которому будем преобразовывать, а потом применять что-то типа instanceof. Как найдем нужный класс - вызываем нужный метод преобразования

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103730/discussion-between-z-john-and-miron).

Comment: @Miron Оставил несколько комментариев в к вашему коммиту в вашем репозитории